# Why can't GHC find module `Language.Java.Inline.Plugin'

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I am trying to stack build using

I am importing inline-java in the extra-deps in stack.yaml, like this:

```
extra-deps:
  - inline-java-0.8.4@sha256:9862ba980b40792af5f3e29c52929e35ce3e9733d498a0324049b6b1001509ef,1652
```

Here is my program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin=Language.Java.Inline.Plugin #-}
import Language.Java (withJVM)
import Language.Java.Inline
module Main where


main :: IO ()
main = withJVM [] [java| { System.out.println("Hello Java!"); } |]
```

Yet I am getting this error:

```
Preprocessing executable 'MyProject-exe' for MyProject-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'MyProject-exe' for MyProject-0.1.0.0..
<command line>: Could not find module `Language.Java.Inline.Plugin'
Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.

--  While building package MyProject-0.1.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.7.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\274b403a build lib:MyProject exe:MyProject-exe --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may need to add `inline-java` to the executable `dependencies` in your `package.yaml or the corresponding `build-depends` in your `MyProject.cabal`. https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/stack_yaml_vs_cabal_package_file/ explains why you need both.

Comment: This worked. Can you move it to an answer?

Comment: You can write the answer yourself, if you want. I'm lazy! :/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add inline-java to the executable dependencies in your package.yaml or the corresponding build-depends` in your MyProject.cabal. docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/… explains why you need both.